# <href="tel:XXXXXXXXX"> not working in either in android or iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

This is the html code I used:

```
<a href="tel:+9779856565666" data-rel="external">Call</a>
```

I've also included in config.xml file all the following:

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="market:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.4.0" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
```

This is for hybrid application build using PhoneGap desktop app. I have seen most of the posts but couldn't find a solution. Is there anything I am missing out?

Comment: it's working fine I have checked in my android device

Comment: try keeping this - `<allow-intent href="tel:*" />` & remove this - `<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>`. If it doesn't work, add this line - `<access origin="*" />`

Comment: It's still not working. Can you suggest any other ways? Is there any chance it is because of PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to whitelist your `tel` links. Try installing [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/)